# Spring autowired object is null in postcontruct method

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, postconstruct

I have a below setup

```
@Service
public class TestDispatcherImpl implements Dispatcher <MobilePushNotification> {

    @Autowired
    private A a;

    @Autowired
    private B b;

    @Autowired
    private C c;


    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {} {
     b.someMethod(); //GETTING A NULL POINTER EXCEPTION, 
                     //in fact all the beans are null

    }
}

public interface Dispatcher <T extends Notification> {

}
```

What is happening ?

Comment: Do you have <context:component-scan base-package="< package " /> in your applicationContext and how are A, B and C classes annotated?

Comment: yes i do, the implementations of a,b & c are annotated as @service .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try removing the extra curly-braces:

```
public void initialize() {} {
                         ^^
 b.someMethod(); //GETTING A NULL POINTER EXCEPTION, 
                 //in fact all the beans are null

}
```

I suspect the initializer block, where you call `b.someMethod()`, is invoked prior to Spring wiring the dependencies. Therefore `b` is `null` at this point.

Answer (score 0):

try to handle it using the context:

simple to use this interface

org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanPostProcessor